# Filter table data from first character of string in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with some records and a textbox. I want to filter table data based on string entered in textbox on keyup event.

Currently I am using a code block which filter the table data but it search the record in table which exist anywhere in the string.

For example:- If I enter 'ab' in textbox it filter the table record with strings contains the keyword 'ab' like abcd, babd, cdab etc.

But my requirement is when I enter the keyword 'ab' in textbox it search only those string which starts from 'ab' like abcd, abdc etc.

Here is my current code:-

```
function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
    var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
    var rowData;
    for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
        rowData = tblData.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
        var styleDisplay = 'none';
        for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
            if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                styleDisplay = '';
            else {
                styleDisplay = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
    }
}
```

Please help guys......

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with jQuery the columns that contain a string beginning with e.g. "ab" of this way:

```
var re = $("#TABLE_ID td").filter(function(i){ return this.innerHTML.startsWith("ab") })
//You can after, get the values of each td of the result of this way
re.map(function(i){return this.innerHTML})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp's test method.

```
var stringData = [
  'aaa', 'aab', 'aac',
  'aba', 'abb', 'abc'
];

var searchPrefix = 'ab';

var result = stringData.filter(function (str) {
  // return true if str has prefix with searchPrefix.
  return (new RegExp('^' + searchPrefix)).test(str);
});

console.log(result);
```

[JavaScript Regexp Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This appears the most elegant solution.

To change search behavior from "*exists anywhere* in the data" into "data *starts with* ". You only need to change one single character, on one single line of your original code and nothing more.

Change this line from this..

```
if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
```

into this...

```
if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) == 0)
```

What it does is forces the *indexOf()* to address zero, instead of allowing mid-string matches.

Below is the whole (already modified) code for copy and paste into a project, such as a html table filter.

```
function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
    var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
    var rowData;
    for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
        rowData = tblData.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
        var styleDisplay = 'none';
        for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
            if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) == 0)
                styleDisplay = '';
            else {
                styleDisplay = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
    }
}
```

- Search_Gridview() = the function's name.
- strKey = input search    characters
- strGV = ID of html table></table